# Possible to have Guid as an optional parameter in asp.net mvc 3 controller action?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3, optional-parameters

I was trying to have an index action on a controller to optionally take a guid like so:

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid id = default(Guid))
```

or like so

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid id = new Guid())
```

I was hoping to take advantage of C#'s optional parameters and my routes are also defined optional parameters:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     new { controller = "somecontroller", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

but calling "somecontroller/index" gives following error...

> The parameters dictionary contains a
>   null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for
>   method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Index(System.Guid)' in
>   'Controllers.SomeController'.
>   An optional parameter must be a
>   reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter

is it just not possible? What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A Guid is not nullable.  For example you can't do this

```
Guid myGuid = null;  // invalid
```

However, in C# 2, some syntactic sugar was added to make value types nullable (by wrapping them in a Nullable object), like so:

```
Guid? myGuid = null; // valid.  myGuid will be Nullable<Guid>.
```

Given that rule, let's take a look at your route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "somecontroller",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional // <-- Optional!!
    });
```

Since you specified in your route that the `id` parameter is optional, you must use a type that can be `null`, **or** you must omit the parameter completely in your action.  So to fix your action, you need to change the `Guid id` parameter to be `Guid? id` and it should work.  After that, you can check the value to make sure it's not null like so:

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid? id) {
    if (id.HasValue) {
        // it's not null, so I can call "id.Value" to get the Guid
    }
}
```

Comment: makes sense and it does fix the problem...why doesn't optional parameter work though? is it how mvc goes through the action constructors? any hints?

Comment: Because the MVC Framework will pass `null` into your action for any optional parameter in the route that it can't find a value for.  It doesn't just call your method without that value.  It has to explicitly pass `null`.  Because a `Guid` is a value type, you can't pass `null` as the argument, even if the parameter has a default value.

Comment: actually the explanation is wrong because int is value type too and it too can't be null but the optional parameters with int work just fine in MVC controller actions while Guid optional parameters don't work (the way @andryuha wanted to use it). So having id = UrlParameter.Optional with id of type int and set to some value in the action signature will work, while the same thing with Guid doesn't work. It obviously has something to do with just the Guid type, could also be a bug in MVC, I guess.

Comment: That's actually not correct, mare.  Optional with respects to routing means the that the Action doesn't need to take in the parameter (i.e. you completely omit it).  If you left the `int` parameter in the method signature, then it would be required, and you'd encounter the same problem the user experienced above.  Optional doesn't mean nullable.  If you what a parameter to be nullable (as the OP indicated) then you must use a nullable type.

Comment: To further clarify:  you can omit the id parameter from your action altogether, or you can use a nullable type.  With the given route, you couldn't use a regular `int`, and then expect to hit your action even when a value isn't supplied.  It would bomb with the same error the OP is experiencing.